# Characteristic Roots Of The Matrix

Tags: matrices

I am supposed to find the characteristic roots of the $2 \times 2$ real matrix $X$ given by:

> $$
>     X=
> \begin{pmatrix}
>  -12& 5\\
>  5&2
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$

How should I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guide:

Compute $$\det \begin{bmatrix} -12 -\lambda & 5 \\ 5 & 2-\lambda \end{bmatrix}=0$$

You should obtain a quadratic equation.

Solve for $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

Well you should define the [characteristic polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CharacteristicPolynomial.html) as

$$p_X(\lambda) := \det(X - \lambda\mathbb{1})$$

This is the polynomial that will give you the characteristic roots when you use the relation

$$p_X(\lambda) = 0$$

This is important in obtaining the [Eigenvalues](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Eigenvalue.html) related to the matrix $X$. For your matrix $X$ you will have that (use as a reference or a hint)

> $$p_X(\lambda) = \lambda^2 + 10\lambda - 49 = 0 \implies \lambda_1 = -5 + \sqrt{74} \text{ and } \lambda_2 = -5 - \sqrt{74}$$

Then you'll have two eigenvalues related to two eigenvectors.